# GWT CellTree Selection of Parent nodes

Tags: gwt, selectionmodel

I'm trying to use the GWT CellTree to display a heterogeneous, hierarchical data model. I need to be able to a single selection, but be able to select Parent nodes as well as child nodes.  For example, if you look at GWT's own [example](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/user/javadoc/com/google/gwt/examples/cellview/CellTreeExample2.java), you'll see that they only provide one selection model for the leave nodes.

I tried to extend their example by providing one selection model for all nodes.  However, that seems impossible.  So what I ended up with where 3 SelectionModels one for each node type (Composer, PlayList, Song).

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **getNodeInfo** function of your **TreeViewModel** you have to pass the selectionModel to each new **DefaultNodeInfo** instance at each level.

```
return new DefaultNodeInfo<MyDTO>(dataProvider,new MyDTOCell(),selectionModel,null);
```

and then in the SelectionChangeEventHandler you have do something like this:

```
selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
        Object object = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
        if (object instanceof MyRootDTO)
        {
              // DO SOMETHING with root level selected node
        }
        else if (object instanceof MySecondLevelDTO) {
        // DO SOMETHING WITH 2. level selected node
        }
        // additional levels
});
```

**Update**:
In order to get around the typing problem, you can define an abstract base class which is extended by all your DTO's.

```
public abstract class BaseModel  {

    public static final ProvidesKey<BaseModel> KEY_PROVIDER = new ProvidesKey<BaseModel>() {
      public Object getKey(BaseModel item) {
        return item == null ? null : item.getId();
      }
    };

    public abstract Object getId();
}
```

In your DTO's you extend the BaseModel and implement the abstract getId() method:

```
public class MyDTO extends BaseModel {
        @Override
        public Object getId() {
             //return unique ID (i.e. MyDTO_1)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I guess I'm missing something because, I thought that the selectionModel is strongly typed.  So for the root node you'd have to pass in a selectionModel<MyRootDTO> and for second level you have to pass in selectionModel<MySecondLevelDTO>.  How would I get around that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's right. However as a workaround you could create an abstract Base class (BaseModel) which implements the ProviderKey interface. All your DTO's extend this BaseModel class. (see update on my answer)

Comment: I ended up with a different approach.  I created a SelectionModelController that houses 3 selectionModels.  After a few days of playing around with this widget, I realized that it doesn't need my other needs so I wrote my own.  Thanks again.